# How do I return a symbol from a C function in gambit scheme?

Tags: c, scheme, ffi, gambit

I've got a C function behind a c-lambda which needs to do some grubbing around with a select(2) call and decide on a scheme symbol to return as an indication of what it did, and whether an error condition occurred.  How one gets hold of a named symbol as a ___SCMOBJ (or anything more appropriate) from C isn't explained in the docs, and the wiki seems to have fallen over.  It's also not immediately obvious from gambit.h whether there's a macro for this purpose.

Is this possible out of the box?  My workaround at the moment is to pass in returnable symbols as arguments to the function, but with a larger set of symbols I want to be able to return, that's going to get very unwieldy very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question [on the gambit-c mailing list](https://mercure.iro.umontreal.ca/pipermail/gambit-list/2013-February/006411.html).  There were three main responses:

1. [Export string->symbol to C](https://mercure.iro.umontreal.ca/pipermail/gambit-list/2013-February/006413.html)
2. [Build a lookup table before calling into C](https://mercure.iro.umontreal.ca/pipermail/gambit-list/2013-February/006412.html)
3. [Upgrade gambit](https://mercure.iro.umontreal.ca/pipermail/gambit-list/2013-February/006418.html)

I'm going with (1) for the moment, because I want to be compatible with Debian Squeeze's gambit and I don't *think* the performance hit will be significant yet.